# if loop running on both true and false

Tags: javascript, arrays

A little confused, I have the below code that loops through an array and if the value is not in another array push it in. But whether the indexOf statement evaluates to true or false it gets pushed into the array - not quite sure why that is.

```
function findUnique(fieldId) {
  let uniques = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    console.log(uniques.indexOf(data[i][fieldId]) === -1);
    if (uniques.indexOf(data[i][fieldId] === -1)) {
      uniques.push(data[i][fieldId]);
    }
  }
  return uniques;
}
```

Say there are 2 items in data...

first pass through will log out -1 because it is not in the array, then pushes to array...

second pass logs out 0 because it is in the array but all pushes it into the array...

uniques logs out as ['a', 'a']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a typo. You're currently looking for `false` in your array.

Change

```
if (uniques.indexOf(data[i][fieldId] === -1)) {
```

to

```
if (uniques.indexOf(data[i][fieldId]) === -1) {
```